# How to validate mandatory fields in the front-end and back-end

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am creating my form and I need to make some validations of some fields that are mandatory both in the front and in the back and that are not allowed to send until duly filled out.

The following is the form with the fields.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
          Applicant</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketIdAppliInput">Id:</label>
            <input maxlength="9" required id="ticketIdAppliInput" type="text" name="matricula" onkeypress="if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode))) return false;" class="form-control form-control-user" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Full name:</label>
            <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
            <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Send</button>
```

The following is the JavaScript function that sends the data.

```
function f_submitForm() {
    form.append("ticketIdAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketIdAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketNameAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketNameAppliInput").value);
    form.append("ticketEmailAppliInput", document.getElementById("ticketEmailAppliInput").value);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Add minimal reproducible example, form controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreateNewTicket()
        {
            var ticketIdAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketIdAppliInput"];
            var ticketNameAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketNameAppliInput"];
            var ticketEmailAppliInput = Request.Form["ticketEmailAppliInput"];

        try
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {               
                var ticket = new TK_HD_TICKETS
                {
                    CUSTOMER_ID = ticketIdAppliInput,
                    CUSTOMER_FULLNAME = ticketNameAppliInput,
                    CUSTOMER_EMAIL = ticketEmailAppliInput,
                    };
                    var result = ticketCreate.CreateNewTicket(ticket);

                    // If the ticket was not saved, the transaction is finished and we return the error message
                    if (!result.Success)
                    return Json(new TicketResult
                    {
                        IsValid = false,
                        Error = "The ticket could not be created, please try again."
                    });
            }
        }catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            // Failed to try to register data in the database
            foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
            foreach (var validationError in e.ValidationErrors)
                Console.WriteLine("Property: " + validationError.PropertyName + " Error: " +
                                  validationError.ErrorMessage);

            return Json(new TicketResult
            {
                IsValid = false,
                Error = "There was an error creating the ticket, please try again."
            });
        }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the problem, but you could hide the submit button and have a change event that checks if all fields are filled. If they are, you show the button, if not, it stays hidden.

As for the back-end part, you could use regular expressions to check you're getting what you want (also helps preventing injections)

Comment: Another option would be to "catch" the submit event and prevent it from occuring, then use your own handler to validate the fields :) 

If you're jusing JQuery, you can use ".preventDefault()" and ".stopPropagation()" to achieve that.

Comment: You can leave me an example of how to make the change event that verifies if all the fields are filled

Comment: Why not just add the `required` attribute to all of the `input`s that are required? You've marked this `c#` but there is no C# code here. Finally, that JavaScript function doesn't make any sense out of context. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] of the back-end code that receives this data if you'd like help with that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If I do it with the required tag in html you can inspect the item through the browser and delete it and it is what I do not want, if I had already done so

Comment: And you can do the same with any JavaScript you add. That's why you validate on the back-end also.

Comment: @HereticMonkey check again the question I just made the minimum reproducible example showing the controller

Comment: I don't see how you're getting the data from the HTML form to the (MVC?) action. All you'd need to do is check if those variables that start with `ticket` match `string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticketIdAppliInput)`. If so, it's invalid.

Comment: @MauricioCárdenas You don't need jQuery to use `preventDefault()`, and you only need that, not `stopPropagation()` (which also doesn't require jQuery).

Comment: @HereticMonkey It is correct I use MVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199656/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-heretic-monkey).

Comment: Most of this can be handled by your Model. Add the appropriate validation attributes to your public propertied and use the appropriate HTML helpers in your cshtml page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, you're right. I had a brain fart right there. Still, stopPropagation() helps sometimes. I've had issues where I had preventDefault() only, but it wouldn't stop the parent trigger from happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create yourself a model class:

```
public class MyData {
  [Required]
  [StringLength(9)]
  [Display(Name="Id")]
  public string ticketIdAppliInput {get;set;}
  [Required]
  public string ticketNameAppliInput {get;set;}
  [Required]
  public string ticketEmailAppliInput {get;set;}
}
```

Change your controller to take this class as input:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateNewTicket(MyData data) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    return Json(...);
  return View(data);
}
```

Then change your view to actually use this class (I'll do the first input for you):

```
@model MyData
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div id="informacionTicket" class="user">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h4 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
          Applicant</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="mb-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ticketIdAppliInput)
            @Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.ticketIdAppliInput, new { @type="text", @class="form-control form-control-user"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.ticketIdAppliInput)
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketNameAppliInput">Full name:</label>
            <input maxlength="100" id="ticketNameAppliInput" type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control form-control-user" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ticketEmailAppliInput">Email:</label>
            <input maxlength="100" id="ticketEmailAppliInput" type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Send</button>
}
```

Comment: I would rather not change the html tags that I already have created, you have some other option

Comment: Your current view doesn't currently handle displaying error messages from the server, so you will need to address that anyhow.  But if you really want to continue down that path...  Then you'll need to change your inputs so that the values you may have posts get put back into the inputs on error as well.  And then handle all your validations on the client side by writing custom javascript.

Comment: You will spend more time trying to avoid doing it the right way than just doing it the right way.  You shouldn't be trying to avoid making and using a model if you are using a MVC framework... That is the M in MVC after all.

Answer (score 0):

In Html you can simple use required tag and there are lots of jquery library which will provide validation for you as well show popup custom message.

Comment: The HTML required attribute does not validate the inputs on the back end.  As such, those attributes should be considered an html progressive enhancement, and not to be trusted.  It's far too easy to bypass, so you need to also make the same check server-side.